# How to notify certain thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In below code My application run may thread. But How to I notify certain thread.
My task is print all the thread from Server object **`msg`** String when String **`msg`** change.

```
class Server{ 
    static String msg;

    synchronized void setMsg(String msg){
        this.msg = msg ; 
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void proccess(){
        while(true){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+Server.msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my thread class :

```
class MyThread  extends Thread { 
    Server ser ;
    public MyThread(Server ser) {
        this.ser = ser ; 
        this.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        ser.proccess();
    }
}
```

Main Meth() :

```
class Thread_test {
    static String[] name = null ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Server ser = new Server();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            MyThread t1 = new MyThread(ser);
            t1.setName("Thread "+i);
        }
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ser.sendMsg("Msg : current time is = " + System.currentTimeMillis());       
        }
    }
```

I change the Server message string once every 5 sec. When change the message I call **notifyAll()**. This notifyall is wakeup all the waiting thread. But what I want is i.e : I create 10 thread and setName Thread_1 Thread_2 ..etc., Now I want to notify some thread like Thread_1, Thread_4 and  Thread_9. I try below func

```
     while(true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ser.sendMsg("Msg : current time is = " +   System.currentTimeMillis()); 
            for ( Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet() ){
                if(t.getName().equals("Thread_1") || t.getName().equals("Thread_4") || t.getName().equals("Thread_9")){
                    t.notify();
                }
             }  
        }
```

I got **`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`**

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you're referring to the `notify` method declared in `Object`, you don't _notify_ threads. What do you actually mean?

Comment: Which line is the exception ?

Comment: Exception line :          t.notify()

Comment: Have you wrapped it in synchronized block ? I think you need to wrap it in synchronized block.

Comment: Please try something like this  synchronized(t) {
        t.notify();
      }

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: and what will that accomplish? Yes, it will get rid of the exception, but it won't solve his overall problem.

Comment: FYI: You should never `.start()` a thread from within its own constructor.  Doing so allows the thread to see the `Thread` object before the object is completely constructed.  It can cause serious problems that might or might _not_ show up right away.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, There is a very important reason why the library forces you to `synchronize` on the object that you want to notify, and your example doesn't show it.  Read Oracle's "Guarded Blocks" tutorial to learn more:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: You want me to explain why the synchronized block is needed or ? What do you want exactly ? More Details ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: I'm asking why you're notifying an object that is not being used as a monitor in the critical bit of code that he needs to notify.

Comment: @AryaGM, Next time your code throws an exception, please read the javadoc for the function call that threw it, and find out _why_ it can throw the exception.  Then come ask here if you don't understand the explanation.  (The explanation for why `t.notify()` throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` is about as simple as it gets.  If you've read it and you still don't understand it, then that may be a sign that you haven't learned enough of the Java language and its libraries to start playing with threads.)

Comment: @AryaGM, You should not ever call `t.wait()` or `t.notify()` when `t` is a `Thread`.  It can have unexpected side effects because the `Thread` class also uses `wait()` and `notify()` for its own purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Server{ 
    String msg;

    void sendMsg(String msg){
        this.msg = msg ;
    }
    public void proccess() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) { 
                Thread.currentThread().wait();          
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+this.msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the class object **`wait()`** and add **`Thread.wait()`** and add

```
synchronized(t){
    t.notify();
}
```

I don't know it is a correct war or Not. If it wrong provide efficient way.